# How to Display the Whole Answer with PARI/GP?

Tags: math-software

I am staring to learn PARI/GP. I am able to set the precision to a high degree and display the output; however, the output is severely truncated. I, if need be, would like to display up to $40,000$ digits but what appears is but a limited version of the output followed by $[***]$.

Does anyone know how to display the output on the screen up to the inputted level of precision?

Comment: Tune `default(lines, ...)` (by default it is $25$ iirc). Or just `write("name.ext", ...)`.

Comment: Thank you. The first suggestion seems to work. Question: what did you mean by write("name.ext", ...)? What does that do?

Comment: It writes its arguments to a file (type `?write` or `??write`).

Comment: Thank you again